# Cannot access my desktop on windows 8 using my windows live account

Tags: windows-8, boot, passwords, login

It tells me to change my password which I do from my xbox since I cannot get online with my laptop.

I have changed the password multiple times.

I cannot get into the BIOS.

How can I log into my windows 8 computer or reset to factory settings without having to go into the actual desktop?

Comment: The BIOS has nothing to do with the Windows OS - so that would likely be a separate issue.

Comment: What I mean is I can't access anything that I normally would be able to including BIOS. I am looking for any thing I possibly can to fix this issue but no win keys are working either.

Comment: Okay, well that won't really get you anywhere.  What do you mean "no win keys are working either"?

Comment: Like Win + C for example. I have tried literally anything and everything I could think of and find. F2 hasn't worked either. I have been having friends look up what they can and out of all of us we have found nothing. I know my password, I am the one they literally just changed it because it told me to and I go to use it and it won't accept that password or my old password and I have changed it multiple times trying to get it to work.

Comment: Since it wouldn't I was considering just setting the laptop back to factory settings and starting fresh but I can't seem to do that either. I have no experience with Windows 8 and neither does anyone I have spoken to so far so we are pretty lost.